# Gnome Tweaks change of caps lock to control caused lock out of the system

Tags: gnome3, pureos

I have a brand new [Purism](https://puri.sm) laptop (Librem 15 version 3) with [PureOS](https://pureos.net/) I started up for the first time today.

While setting it up to my liking, I opened [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) to change the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button to be a <kbd>Control</kbd> key. Immediately upon changing the setting (without any other action on my part), the system locked the screen and any further efforts to log in result in the screen going blank momentarily and the lock screen being displayed.

Unsurprisingly, this makes the laptop unusable. There's [no bug report](https://tracker.pureos.net/) [regarding this](https://tracker.pureos.net/w/troubleshooting/).

I was unable to usefully identify the laptop based on the information at [wiki.puri.sm/hw](https://wiki.puri.sm/hw). I consulted my order information instead.

It doesn't appear to boot grub, but I'm not sure I'd know. I can reach the BIOS settings, but nothing there seems to do anything useful. As to rebooting, I did try that immediately. No change. I can log in using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, as suggest, but there's no server running a display at that point. I'll be awaiting a response from Purism before I wipe my user configuration.

Comment: A complete power cycle seems the first thing to try. I see that Purism laptops use coreboot, rather than a more traditional BIOS. Do you know if it boots grub? If it does then you can probably stop it at the grub stage and boot into single user mode. At that point you could wipe out your user configuration and see if this fixes the issue. Another option is to switch to a different virtual terminal, using ctrl+alt+f3, and log in there.

Comment: Not sure what BIOS settings there are to be changed - typically coreboot loads a payload (very quickly). It is **expected** that there is no server running a display when logging in via ctrl-alt-f3 - this is a good thing as your display server seems to be crashing. If you don't want to wipe out everything, you could run `mv .config my_old.config;sync` and then power cycle quickly to stop anything from recreating the (possibly) faulty config. You can access all your changes/configuration in the my_old.config directory and copy them back. If you want help from Purism rather than us, I will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Purism support and commenter @icarus above, I was able to remove the offending configuration at `~/.config/dconf/user` and rebooting.

Moreover, I was able to achieve my intended result by modifying `/etc/defaults/keyboard` as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087739/remapped-capslock-key-is-ignored-set-by-xkboptions-in-etc-default-keyboard).